# Is there a way to set a SQL Server job scheduled to run every 30 seconds?

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, sql-job

When I try to create a Schedule the minimum amount of time I can choose from is 1 minute, is there a way to reduce this to seconds?

Comment: What on earth do you need to run twice a minute?

Comment: aye, its not my choice, its the pointy haired one's... we need to send some push notifications and they want them asap...specially because local pointy hair is having a meeting with the bigger pointy hairs soon, ands want to show the demo working FAST (not having to wait a minute for the process to kick in...we'll probably just add a button for the demo though..)

Comment: Haha I wouldn't recommend that!

Comment: If new data is not generated this often, you could consider starting the job with a trigger. Which has it's own nasitness involved (the trigger operates inside the transaction), but might be preferable in your buisness case. Another option: let the application that is doing the database modification also start the job

Comment: Yes we are probably going to use the last option you mention, but for the mean while marc_s'answer is pretty solid. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article here [SQL Server Job Scheduling](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/sqlserverjobscheduling/2288/) says you can - just not directly from the UI (the seconds aren't exposed as a valid choice).

See in about the middle of the page:

> **Schedules for frequent executing jobs**
>
> SQL server jobs can have high running
>   frequency with interval less than 1
>   minute. But this capability is not
>   exposed to SQL agent GUI, only “Hours”
>   and “Minutes” are supported.
>
> This can be achieved by calling the
>   stored procedure
>   msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule or
>   msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobschedule.
>
> The stored procedures have a parameter
>   @freq_subday_type, it has three values
>   according to BOL:
>
> Value     Description (unit)
>   0x1           At the specified time.
>   0x4           Minutes.
>   0x8           Hours.
>
> For the same column in
>   msdb..sysjobschedules table, it has
>   four values, **which includes 0x2 for
>   seconds.**
>
> Though 0x2 is not documented for the
>   two stored procedures, it can accept
>   the value and create the schedule
>   correctly, e.g. this script will
>   create a job runs every 30 seconds
>   everyday.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create a DTS job for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx